# Why does basename return the compiled filename?

Tags: python

Running `os.path.basename(__file__)` sometimes give me the filename as `foo.py`, but other times it gives `foo.pyc`. I understand that the pyc is the compiled file, which is then probably used everytime after it was compiled. I'm just confused as to why the `basename` returns the pyc filename? Is that normal? Secondly, how can I make it always return the uncompiled filename or without the extension?

Comment: Is this called in an imported module?

Comment: `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0] + os.path.extsep + "py"`

Comment: You probably can't change the initial value of `__file__`, but you can separate the extension from the filename using `os.path.splitext()`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `os.path.basename()`.  It's solely determined by `__file__`.  Basename is just returning the leaf component of the path.  The first time you import the file, you'll get the `.py` path in `__file__`.  After that, if a `.pyc` version is available and up-to-date, it will use that instead.

Comment: Do you use Python2.7? The behaviour of compiled modules is different in Python 3.5 where the behaviour you describe does not happen.

Comment: Good point.  My comment applies to Python 2, which is what I assume OP is using.  Python3 uses a more sophisticated mechanism for caching compiled Python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, `__file__` reflects the file that was actually loaded for the module<sup>*</sup>. When importing a module, Python will try to first locate a `.pyc` file, and if found that'll be the filename used, otherwise it'll be the `.py` file.

It *may* be that if `__file__` points to a `.py` on the *next* run of the interpreter you'll find it loaded a `.pyc` file instead, as Python will try to create a cache file if it can. Also note that there may *not* be a `.py` source file; some projects are distributed only in the form of `.pyc` files. Last but not least, Python never creates a `.pyc` file for the top-level script.

A fail-safe way to generate a `.py` source file filename is to simply strip the `c` from the end; you could include a `d` to handle `.pyd` files (optimised bytecode, currently only stripping asserts) too:

```
sourcefile = __file__.rstrip('cd')
```

Do check if the file actually exists!

---

<sup>*</sup> Python 3 changed where the cached bytecode file is stored, and `__file__` will use the source file path if there is one even if a `.pyc` file exists.

Comment: Why do you prefer `rstrip` over `splitext`?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: simpler. It works for all loadable module extensions (`.dll`, `.so`, `.pyc`, `.pyd` and `.py`)

Answer (score 2):

`__file__` is defined before you get a chance to do anything about it.  If you want to get the `.py` file instead, you'll need to figure out what it is yourself:

```
without_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
with_new_ext = os.path.extsep.join(without_ext, "py")
```

Sometimes, the `.py` file doesn't even exist.  Since you wrote the code, you are unlikely to have deleted it, but there is that possibility.  To make sure it exists, use `os.path.isfile()`